# Model should communicate View via ViewMediator. Can Vo ( a part of Model) communicate directly

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller

I generally keep the references of VOs inside the related View. Keeping Vo references inside the related view, help a lot in making direct assignments to the changes. I doubt if keeping Vo references inside View, a right thing and as per the principles of MVC ( I use robotlegs ) . Because as per mvc, model should communicate view via the view mediator. And Vos are something related to the model.

So what is the right way. How should the VOs get updated, when there is a change in View ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to take the literal approach to MVC, ValueObjects should be immutable - values don't change after they've been assigned.  If you treat a VO as a changeable part of the data, then it should be in the model. But if you're using them as references to values, you might need to keep them someplace where they're available in the scope of your app.  If that needs to be the View, then you put it there.

Basically, see how you're using them and how it applies to what you're doing and settle on a single approach that works for you.  As long as you're consistent, it really shouldn't matter if it's following the 'rules'.  Besides, as far as I'm concerned, they're just guidelines anyway.

Comment: amm.. i couldnot understand this. "ValueObjects should be immutable". Then how come they will represent the changing values of a "View". Let's say i have a listbox with 100 values. And selectedIndex is 5. The "Vo" saves the selectedIndex. And when a new item is selected in the listbox, it must change corresponding variable in the Vo accordingly. Right?

Comment: In this case it could easily be a model property - selectedIndex.  VOs are more like currency rates or date ranges - take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object  But in the C# example there they mention that the C# VO is mutable - so again, like I said before, use this all as guidelines and don't take it as the only way to implement your app.  Stick with one thing and use it to it's best effect.  If you need the VO to be mutable - make it mutable.